# iPod backup software

Tags: windows, backup, itunes, ipod, software-rec

Is there an iPod backup solution besides using iTunes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SharePod](http://www.getsharepod.com/) is a good alternative.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For iPod and iPhone. Good software.

http://www.copytrans.net/

&

http://www.xilisoft.com/ipod-rip.html

Answer (score 1):

You can always take a look on http://alternativeto.net/desktop/sharepod if you would like to lookup more alternatives. I have heard good things about CopyTrans and Touch Copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [libimobiledevice](http://libimobiledevice.org/) to backup your device. You cannot restore it, however. The software is not that advanced.

Answer (score 0):

well if you want a low level way of doing it - enable hidden files, find and copy the contents of the  iPod_Control folder, find the renamed MP3s, and fix the tags with your favourite bulk retagger, and the metadata